# Eclipse local history with P4V

Tags: eclipse, perforce

I want to see the Eclipse Local History of one of my files, but I have P4V and it seems like it has made it so that I only have See Revision History instead of See Local History. How do I get the local history of my file when perforce has altered the eclipse tooling? Is it possible?

Comment: Where are you looking for the Local History options? Try 'Compare With > Local History' in the right click context menu (with a single file selected)

Comment: Did do that, says there's nothing to be found. I'm guessing Perforce just deleted everything permanently.

Comment: The local history only lasts for a few days so it may just have been deleted by Eclipse normally. See Preferences > General > Workspace > Local History for configuration.